# Container name added to blob filename by GetBlockBlobReference() method

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am implementing a custom activity for Azure Data Factory pipeline to move a blob file from a container to another. Names for source/destination files are passed to the DotNetActivity from input/output datasets of the pipeline's custom activity. To make it simple, let's have a source filename as 'input.txt' and destination filename as 'output.txt'. Both containers 'upload' and 'processed' exist.

Following code does the copying part, anyhow result is not what I would expect.

```
logger.Write("Source filename  : {0}", sourceFilename);       // => input.txt
logger.Write("Destin. filename : {0}", destinationFileName);  // => output.txt

CloudBlobContainer sourceContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("upload");
CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceFilename);
CloudBlobContainer destinationContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("processed");
CloudBlockBlob destinationBlob = destinationContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(destinationFileName);

logger.Write("Source blob: {0}", sourceBlob.Name);            // => input.txt
logger.Write("Destination blob: {0}", destinationBlob.Name);  // => processed/output.txt ???

destinationBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(sourceBlob);
```

As result, blob 'processed/output.txt' is created to 'processed' container, whereas purpose is to have blob named as 'output.txt'.

Why the 'processed/' prefix is added to destination filename? How to get rid of the prefix?

Comment: Noticed that when Data Factory is re-deployed (published) from VisualStudio to Azure, changed .NET implementation is not rebuild but deployment loads the existing .NET DLL. Apparently problem was caused by earlier version of DotNetActivity. I am now building DotNetActivity manually before publishing Data Factory changes, and above code works as expected. 

Seems like false alarm caused by user error :-O

Comment: please provide you update in the comment as your answer. Since you resolved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticed that when Data Factory is re-deployed (published) from VisualStudio to Azure, changed .NET implementation is not rebuild but deployment loads the existing .NET DLL. Apparently problem was caused by earlier version of DotNetActivity. I am now building DotNetActivity manually before publishing Data Factory changes, and above code works as expected.
(missed to point out the resolution earlier)